# Convert seconds to hh:mm:ss in C

Tags: c, algorithm

I need to write a program using struct and pointers, in which it converts seconds to hours, minutes and seconds.
Could someone explain to me what is wrong with my code that generates the wrong result? `

```
   #include <stdio.h>

    struct t_horario{
        int horas;
        int minutos;
        int segundos;
    };

    void converte (int segundos, struct t_horario *h);
/*void converte (int segundos, struct t_horario *h){
    h->horas = (segundos/3600);
    h->minutos = (segundos/60)%60;
    h->segundos = (segundos%60);
} */

    int main() {
       struct t_horario tempo;
       printf("Entre com o numero de segundos: ");
       scanf("%d", &tempo.segundos);

       printf("%d HH, %d MM and %d SS",tempo.horas,tempo.minutos,tempo.segundos);

       return 0;
    }
    void converte (int segundos, struct t_horario *h){
        h->horas = (segundos/3600);
        h->minutos = (segundos/60)%60;
        segundos = (segundos%60);
    }
```

Comment: You need `h->segundos = segundos % 60;` in the function. You missed the `h->` in the actual function, even though it is present in the skeleton after the function declaration, which make the later omission more odd.  You don't need the parentheses around the division for `horas` (or `segundos`).  You do need the parentheses (for clarity) in the `(minutos / 60) % 60` expression.

Comment: But even adjusting this in the code I get the wrong result. 
For example when I type 9000 seconds, it says that it is equivalent to 6961368 HH, 35 MM and 90000 SS

Comment: You also have to call the `converte()` function — you don't.  You should read the input into a different variable (maybe `int segundos;` and `if (scanf("%d", &segundos) == 1) { converter(segundos, &tempo); printf(…); }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>*Converting comments into an answer.*</sup>

You need `h->segundos = segundos % 60;` in the function. You missed the `h->` in the actual function, even though it is present in the skeleton after the function declaration, which makes the later omission odder. You don't need the parentheses around the division for `horas` (or `segundos`). You do need the parentheses (for clarity) in the `(minutos / 60) % 60` expression.

You also have to call the `converte()` function — you don't.  You should read the input into a different variable too.

```
int segundos;
if (scanf("%d", &segundos) == 1)
{
    converter(segundos, &tempo);
    printf(…);
}
```

That leads to this code (source code `hms37.c`, program `hms37`).  Note that it prints the input as well as the outputs, and ends the printing with a newline.  That's an important safety measure — it means you can be sure that the program is processing what you thought you entered.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct t_horario
{
    int horas;
    int minutos;
    int segundos;
};

static void converte(int segundos, struct t_horario *h);

int main(void)
{
    struct t_horario tempo;
    int segundos;
    printf("Entre com o numero de segundos: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &segundos) == 1)
    {
        converte(segundos, &tempo);
        printf("%d seconds == %d HH, %d MM and %d SS\n",
               segundos, tempo.horas, tempo.minutos, tempo.segundos);
    }

    return 0;
}

static void converte(int segundos, struct t_horario *h)
{
    h->horas = segundos / 3600;
    h->minutos = (segundos / 60) % 60;
    h->segundos = segundos % 60;
}
```

Some sample runs:

```
$ hms37
Entre com o numero de segundos: 90000
90000 seconds == 25 HH, 0 MM and 0 SS
$ hms37
Entre com o numero de segundos: 84921
84921 seconds == 23 HH, 35 MM and 21 SS
$ hms37
Entre com o numero de segundos: 3872
3872 seconds == 1 HH, 4 MM and 32 SS
$ hms37
Entre com o numero de segundos: 1844
1844 seconds == 0 HH, 30 MM and 44 SS
$ hms37
Entre com o numero de segundos: 56
56 seconds == 0 HH, 0 MM and 56 SS
$
```